# Appium - webdriverio - ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4723

Tags: appium, webdriver-io

Intermittently I get `ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4723` when running tests in a container connecting to an android device.  I have not been able to reproduce it consistently but it happens often.

I tried setting 'address' in the config file to '0.0.0.0' and '127.0.0.1' but neither resolved the issue.  I tried adding 'wdaStartupRetries: 3' as well, but that did not fix the issue either.

Do you have thoughts on what might be causing this issue or how to fix it?  Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure your Appium node is up and running? Is it possible for another process to still be blocking your node?